# Why does this not work? I'm adding a pause button to my Sprite Kit game

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, touchesbegan, sklabelnode

So I added a pause button to my game and the freezing and unfreezing of the view works. However I want it to display a message saying "PAUSE" over the screen if the view is currently frozen. But if I'm touching my pause button it doesn't display the label. It's really strange, because I discovered that if I'm turning my device to landscape mode, the "PAUSE" message appears. (and vice versa too, so if I touch the button in landscape mode and turn my device to portrait, the pause label appears)

Can anyone figure this out?

```
-(void)gameScene{


 //Pause
    pauseButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"pause.jpg"];
    pauseButton.position = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2, screenHeight-80);
    pauseButton.zPosition = 5;
    pauseButton.name = @"pauseButton";
    pauseButton.size = CGSizeMake(80, 80);

    [self addChild:pauseButton];

    //Pause Label (wenn Pause gedrückt wird)
    pauseLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Arial"];
    pauseLabel.text = @"PAUSE";
    pauseLabel.fontSize = 70;
    pauseLabel.position = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2);
    pauseLabel.zPosition = 5;
    pauseCount = 1;
}




-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

//Pause Button
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];


    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"pauseButton"]) {            

        pauseCount++;


        if (pauseCount%2 == 0) {
            self.scene.view.paused = YES;
            [self addChild:pauseLabel];

        }

        else{
            self.scene.view.paused = NO;
            [pauseLabel runAction:remove];
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Try adding the pause label when the view appears, then immediately setting it 'hidden,' then reveal/hide when pause is pressed?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! tried that out; still doesn't work :/ (in fact it's showing the exact same symptoms as before - landscape/portrait rotation

Comment: sounds like you present the first scene in viewwilllayoutsubviews without checking if there is already a running scene, cause that method is called whenever the view resizes (ie rotates)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D the first scene is actually a main menu (which is set up by the viewcontroller). after pressing a "play" button there, it transitions to the game scene. actually, i don't even know that viewwilllayoutsubviews existed until now.. (i am fairly new to programming though)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pausing game in Sprite Kit: Why doesn't this work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952439/pausing-game-in-sprite-kit-why-doesnt-this-work)